# Crystal Report showing empty when DB query returns data

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

Not sure what's going on here. I'm creating a report using two tables. I do an inner join on both tables to obtain the rows I need. I'm sure the proper rows exist because I have taken the DB query that Crystal Reports generates for you and ran it on sql developer and it returns the appropriate rows. Not sure why my report would return empty if it's grabbing the proper rows and the DB has been verified using Crystal Report's "Verify Database" tool.

Comment: Check and Double check each section of your report, you might have left some Suppression formula. Secondly check and double check Record Selection filters in the report.

Comment: @aMazing Thank you, this turned out to be the problem. Please set your comment as the answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check and **Double check** each section of your report, you might have left some Suppression formula. Secondly check and **double check** Record Selection filters in the report.

Sometimes what we don't see the first time, miraculously appears the second time.